# Implementing of barcodes

Tags: sharepoint-online, barcodes

I am having difficult in applying qr code in my list. May i know how to insert qr code in the list? The qr code should consists the details of lists. For example, my lists are name,price and description. So after i scan the qr code. It should show the name,price and description. So may i know how to do it?